# Applying the divergence theorem to the graph of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

**This question relates to a proof of some theorem, and to avoid reckless discussion, I will incorporate some of the statements in the theorem that might seem irrelevant at first glance.**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ is either a constant or $\infty$, let $M$ be the graph of $f$ defined by
$$M=\{(x,f(x))\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\},$$
and let $g$ be the metric on $M$ induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Assume that $f_i f_j=O_2(|x|^{-q})$ for some $q>\frac{n-2}{2}$. Here, the subscripts on $f$ denote partial differentiation, and $O_2(|x|^{-q})$ refers to a function in $C_{-q}^2$. We say that $f\in C_{-q}^2$ if
$$|f(x)|+|x|\cdot|\partial f(x)|+|x|^2\cdot|\partial^2 f(x)|<C|x|^{-q}$$
for some constant $C$. $\partial f$ is the vector field whose components are $f_i$'s.

**Let's bring in the main course.**

According to the author who proved the theorem, we can apply the divergence theorem to get
$$\int_M\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_j\left(\frac{f_{ii}f_j-f_{ij}f_i}{1+|\partial f|^2}\right)\overline{d\mu}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{S_r}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(\frac{f_{ii}f_j-f_{ij}f_i}{1+|\partial f|^2}\right)\overline{\nu}^j\overline{d\mu}_{S_r},$$
where $S_r$ is the sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\overline{\nu}$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field along the sphere.

I didn't see the viability of the equality; after all, if one implements the divergence theorem on $M$, he/she will have to consider an integral over $\partial M$ instead of an expanding sphere. Why is that? Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: When $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$ I do not think that the manifold $M$ has a boundary.

Comment: well, if $M$ is the graph of $f$, then $(x, f(x))$ is a chart of $M$, and if you restrict that to a ball of radius $r$, you get a manifold with boundary. On which you can, of course, apply the divergence theorem, and if you afterwards let the radius tend to infinity you may well end up with what you wrote down. I did not check whether the formula you wrote down results from applying it, but it looks a bit as if.

Comment: why did you tag this with the 'general-relativity' tag?

Comment: Thank you guys. Indeed, $M$ does **NOT** possess manifold boundary (distinguished from topological boundary): every point of $M$ is an interior point. I tagged the question with "GR" because it's about a special case of the positive mass theorem.